Build docker for postgresql extension pg_bestmatch.rs
I make a Dockerfile as:
FROM postgres:latest

# step 1: Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y build-essential git curl pkg-config libssl-dev libclang-dev llvm-dev && \
    apt-get clean && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# step 2: Install Rust and cargo-pgrx
RUN curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf https://sh.rustup.rs | sh -s -- -y && \
    echo 'source $HOME/.cargo/env' >> $HOME/.bashrc && \
    /bin/bash -c "source $HOME/.cargo/env && cargo install cargo-pgrx --version 0.10.2 --locked"

# step 3: Debugging step to check if cargo is installed
RUN /bin/bash -c "source $HOME/.cargo/env && cargo --version"

# step 4: Debugging step to check if git is installed
RUN git --version

# step 5: Clone the repository and build
RUN /bin/bash -c "source $HOME/.cargo/env && \
    git clone https://github.com/tensorchord/pg_bestmatch.rs.git && \
    cd pg_bestmatch.rs && \
    export RUST_BACKTRACE=full && \
    cargo pgrx init --verbose && \
    cargo pgrx install --verbose"

And, I got stuck in step 5, the below is the log:
 > [6/7] RUN /bin/bash -c "source $HOME/.cargo/env &&     git clone https://github.com/tensorchord/pg_bestmatch.rs.git &&     cd pg_bestmatch.rs &&     export RUST_BACKTRACE=full &&     cargo pgrx init --verbose &&     cargo pgrx install --verbose":
108.3   12: std::sys::backtrace::__rust_begin_short_backtrace::h42629a699b07f548
108.3       at <unknown source file>:<unknown line>
108.3   13: core::ops::function::FnOnce::call_once{{vtable.shim}}::h3bc5f5760445af8a
108.3       at <unknown source file>:<unknown line>
108.3   14: std::sys::pal::unix::thread::Thread::new::thread_start::ha8af9c992ef0b208
108.3       at <unknown source file>:<unknown line>
108.3   15: __clone<unknown>
108.3       at <unknown source file>:<unknown line>
108.3
108.3 Run with COLORBT_SHOW_HIDDEN=1 environment variable to disable frame filtering.
------

Anyone know how to fix that please share.
Try with docker build, to get docker of postgresql and a pg_bestmatch.rs extension.

You will want to be able to debug more easily. If you run each of those commands one at a time manually in your container, which one fails?

In each commands "cargo pgrx init --verbose &&  cargo pgrx install --verbose" get errors.

Those are two commands chained together - does the first one fail without the second? And is the error the same or different as the one you posted above?
